# Clicking on text in a web view changes web view's contents

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

I am developing an application for iPhone. In this app I am storing some 'x' articles (and article numbers are also given) in one view controller and their respective descriptions (shown on web view) in another view controller.

In the description of articles some articles' numbers are given (like 1 , 2 ).  When the user clicks on one of those numbers, the related article description must be opened on the same web view.

Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1-> you need to put the article number as link,

2-> Confirm to the `UIWebViewDelegate`.

3-> Implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` function and within this function you can check for the article number link.

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

**Edited:** Format for the link in **html** `<a href="url">Link text</a>` :In your case it might be ....

```
<a href="my.first.article">1</a>
<a href="my.second.article">2</a>
```

Comment: can u brief how can article number can be kept as a link?